# Updating SP 2013 List Choice(s) Automatically with Fill In Value

Tags: sharepoint-online, list

Is it possible to automatically update the values of the Choice Column Type if it allows fill-in values?

For example, my list has Multiple Choice Display option chosen, but if a user is filling in that field through the form and an option they want to input isn't located as one of the choices, it will obviously fill the value in, but how can I get that value added to the choice options without having to manually go into the list settings and adding it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Base on my test, it is not possible to automatically add value to the choice options for **multiple choice column**, but for **single choice column** is ok, it is by design.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is list view filter working with the dynamically added choice values?? (for both multi and single choice)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this is **not possible** using SharePoint out of the box capabilities.

Fill-in values will not be added to choice column options automatically.

Comment: So my doubt is, what is the use with enabling 'Allow Fill in choices' from REST API perspective ? Because the choice values won't get added dynamically!

Comment: Update choice field options using SharePoint REST API. Check my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/299219/is-it-possible-to-dynamically-add-new-choice-field-values-options-if-i-check-al