# Inconsistent behaviors for the Choice field which allow Fill-in choices inside modern New/Edit form and inside Quick Edit

Tags: sharepoint-online, choice-field

We have a SharePoint choice field named options which allow Fill-in choices and has 3 choices (A + B + C), as follow:-

[image]

Now we have inconsistent behaviors for the Choice field which allow Fill-in choices inside modern New/Edit forms compared to Quick Edit.

So when we create or edit list items using the modern list forms >> the options field will list the choices inside the field definition + the choices that have been fill-in by the user ("MY NEW Choice" in our case):-

[image]

while if we create or edit an item using the list view Quick Edit, the options field will only show the choices inside the field definition and will exclude the choices that have been fill-in by the user as follow:-

[image]

so how we can fix this inconsistency ? and have a standard behavior ? Also is this a bug?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SharePoint Choice field with "Allow 'Fill-in' choices:". Should the Fill-in choice be saved inside the Choice field options?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300372/sharepoint-choice-field-with-allow-fill-in-choices-should-the-fill-in-choi)

Comment: @GaneshSanap no it does not.. as it is targeting a different problem...

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing in quick edit is consistent with how choice columns have always worked. When you create a new item and use a fill in choice, that choice shouldn't appear in the field's dropdown when you create future items. Only the options that appear in the column's settings should appear in the dropdown.

The fill in choice appearing in the dropdown in your screenshot, may be a bug. This has already been outlined in the answer to a previous question:

[SharePoint Choice field with "Allow 'Fill-in' choices:". Should the Fill-in choice be saved inside the Choice field options?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/300372/sharepoint-choice-field-with-allow-fill-in-choices-should-the-fill-in-choi/300381#300381)

As stated in the linked answer, potential bugs can be reported to Microsoft via the Microsoft 365 admin center. You can create a new service request via the Microsoft 365 admin portal. In the menu section, you'll see the "New service request" option within "Support".